# 3D Array of floats in JNI C++

Tags: java, c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, java-native-interface

I'm Having trouble in sending a 3D array with JNI in C++ to Java.

The array should be like this float data[6][26][5]

I have this so far, no look yet.

```cpp
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_JNITest_getArray
(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
PClass* pClass;
jclass cls1;
jclass jcls1;
jclass jcls2;
jobject obj2;

cls1 = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
fid1 = env->GetFieldID(cls1, "ptr", "J");
pClass = (PClass*) env->GetLongField(obj, fid1);

jcls1 = env->FindClass("[[F");
jcls2 = env->FindClass("[F");

jobjectArray array1 = env->NewObjectArray(6, jcls1 , NULL);

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   jobjectArray array2 = env->NewObjectArray(26, jcls2, NULL);

   for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
      jfloatArray array3 = env->NewFloatArray(5);
      env->SetFloatArrayRegion(array3, 0, 5, pClass->data[i][j]);
      env->SetObjectArrayElement(array2, j, array3);
   }

   env->SetObjectArrayElement(array1, i, array2);
 }

env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
return array1;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thomas

Comment: Do you try to convert your C++ code to Java code?

Comment: make a .dll file in c++ that java can read it

Answer (score 0):

Apart from deleting the local references you created when assembling the array and testing the return from `cls1 = env->GetObjectClass(obj);` and `fid1 = env->GetFieldID(cls1, "ptr", "J");`, your code looks correct.

The only line that may be problematic is: `pClass = (PClass*) env->GetLongField(obj, fid1);`. Usually, you would create and fill the array in C++ with something like:

```
data = new float**[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    data[i] = new float*[26];
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
         data[i][j] = new float[5];
    }
 }
```

to then, assign this chunk of memory to your java array as you did in your snippet. Alternatively, you can allocate all memory beforehand and just repoint the 3-dimensional pointers.