# How to pass a 3D element into JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am working on a project and need to do some calculations with a 3D array in C++. I need to pass this 3D array from Java to C++, do some calculations, then return it. I am using JNI and am very new to it so I don't know very much. I am trying to make a sample program to test this and to use it as reference. I have gotten passing a 2D array to C++ but cannot figure out the 3D part. I built the 2D part using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751825/simplest-way-to-pass-float-to-c-via-jni).

This is my C++ code right now (this works for 2D arrays):

```
float** testFunction(float **a)
{

printf("Hello from JNI!\n");
    printf("Point at %d,%d is: %f\n", 1, 2, a[1][2]);

    return a[1][2];
}
jfloat JNICALL Java_JNIArray_integrateWithTrapezoid(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jobjectArray jarr)
{
    int sizex = env->GetArrayLength(jarr);
    jfloatArray dim = (jfloatArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(jarr, 0);
    int sizey = env->GetArrayLength(dim);
    float **localArray;

    localArray = new float *[sizex];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizex; i++)
    {
        jfloatArray oneDim = (jfloatArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(jarr, i);
        jfloat *element = env->GetFloatArrayElements(oneDim, 0);
        localArray[i] = new float[sizey];

        for (int j = 0; j < sizey; j++)
        {
            localArray[i][j] = element[j];
        }
    }

    return testFunction(localArray);
}
```

Any help would be great. I am very in the dark on this. If I forgot to provide any needed information please let me know.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Botje, this worked:

```
void trapezoidalintegral(float ***a)
{

    printf("Hello from JNI!\n");
    printf("Point at %d, %d, %d is: %f\n", 1, 2, 2, a[1][2][2]);

    return;
}

float *thirdLevel(JNIEnv *env, jfloatArray arr)
{
    jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(arr);
    float *ret = new float[len];
    env->GetFloatArrayRegion(arr, 0, len, ret);
    return ret;
}

float **secondLevel(JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray arr)
{
    jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(arr);
    float **ret = new float *[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        jobject item = env->GetObjectArrayElement(arr, i);
        ret[i] = thirdLevel(env, (jfloatArray)item);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(item);
    }
    return ret;
}

float ***firstLevel(JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray arr)
{
    jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(arr);
    float ***ret = new float **[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        jobject item = env->GetObjectArrayElement(arr, i);
        ret[i] = secondLevel(env, (jobjectArray)item);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(item);
    }
    return ret;
}

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_JNIArray_integrateWithTrapezoid(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jobjectArray jarr)
{
    float ***returningArray;

    returningArray = firstLevel(env, jarr);

    trapezoidalintegral(returningArray);

    jclass *pClass;
    jclass cls1;
    jclass jcls1;
    jclass jcls2;
    jobject obj2;

    cls1 = env->GetObjectClass(thisObj);
    // jfieldID fid1 = env->GetFieldID(cls1, "ptr", "J");
    // pClass = (jclass *)env->GetLongField(thisObj, fid1);

    jcls1 = env->FindClass("[[F");
    jcls2 = env->FindClass("[F");

    jobjectArray array1 = env->NewObjectArray(3, jcls1, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        jobjectArray array2 = env->NewObjectArray(3, jcls2, NULL);

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            jfloatArray array3 = env->NewFloatArray(3);
            env->SetFloatArrayRegion(array3, 0, 3, returningArray[i][j]);
            env->SetObjectArrayElement(array2, j, array3);
        }

        env->SetObjectArrayElement(array1, i, array2);
    }

    env->DeleteLocalRef(cls1);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(jcls1);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(jcls2);

    return array1;
}
```

Comment: A jagged 3D array is the same as a jagged 2D array with an extra array of pointers stuffed in the middle. `float **localArray = new float **[sizex];`, then a loop that places `new float *[sizey];` into `localarray` and then another loop that places `new float[sizez]`s into each of the `float*` arrays. Ugly as <expletive deleted>, no? Instead consider one mammoth 1D array and use indexing math to pretend that it's 3D.

Comment: @user4581301 Wouldn't I intialize the array like `float ***localArray = new float**[sizex];`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. Missed a start when I cut and pasted and updated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just structure your program like your data:

```
float* thirdLevel(JNIEnv *env, jfloatArray arr) {
  jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(arr);
  float* ret = new float[len];
  env->GetFloatArrayRegion(arr, 0, len, ret);
  return ret;
}

float** secondLevel(JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray arr) {
  jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(arr);
  float** ret = new float*[len];
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    jobject item = env->GetObjectArrayElement(arr, i);
    ret[i] = thirdLevel(env, (jfloatArray)item);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(item);
  }
  return ret;
}

float*** firstLevel(JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray arr) {
  jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(arr);
  float*** ret = new float**[len];
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    jobject item = env->GetObjectArrayElement(arr, i);
    ret[i] = secondLevel(env, (jobjectArray)item);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(item);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer to show my implementation along with the error message. What am I doing wrong here? I'm pretty sure I am returning the proper data type so I am not sure why I'm getting this error message.

Comment: Your header file promises you will return a `jobjectArray`, while your cpp file promises to return a `float***` (which Java cannot do anything useful with).

Comment: What do you want `Java_JNIArray_integrateWithTrapezoid` to return? From the function name I would think you want just a `jfloat`.

Comment: I updated the answer so it makes more sense - integrate trapezoid was just a previous testing method I used so I will not actually be integrating anything, should have clarified that. I need to return a 3D array as well. I'm pretty sure my problem now is just converting from float*** to a jobjectarray, which I am also not sure how to do.

Comment: The reverse path is already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544629/3d-array-of-floats-in-jni-c)

Comment: thank you so much - I updated the answer with what I have and it worked. I had to comment out two lines though for it to work, any idea why?